# Форматирование ввода/вывода в С/С++

Tags: c, c++

Стоит такая задача:
есть переменная типа int, которую должен ввести пользователь. Как поставить защиту "от дурака", т.е. отрезать ситуацию, когда пользователь вводит абы что с клавиатуры, это абы что записывается в переменную int и "ложит" всю программу. Есть ли какие-то стандартные методы формирования потока ввода. чтобы в переменную int не записывались какие попало символы?

Comment: Читать строку Вам уже посоветовали. Для преобразования в число (ряд чисел) читайте `man strtol` и `SEE ALSO` в нем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У плюсовой библиотеки ввода-вывода есть очень запутанная система для обработки ошибок. Можете начать читать [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/), ну и далее по ссылкам. Правда в ней сам черт ногу сломит. Например условие `std::cin.good() != std::cin.bad()` не всегда истино.

Вот вроде бы правильный код, который делает то что вам нужно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    int number;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    if (std::cin.eof()) {
      std::cout << std::endl << "Terminating." << std::endl;
      return 0;
    } if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cout << "You've entered something wrong." << std::endl;
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } else {
      std::cout << "You've entered " << number << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: премного благодарен

Answer (score 4):

Для преобразования строки в число можно использовать библиотеку `boost::lexical_cast`. У нее есть особенность: при невозможности преобразования выбрасывается исключение. Причем при преобразовании строки в число это происходит всегда, когда в строке есть символы, отличные от тех, что должны быть в записи числа.

Answer (score 3):

Можно на С++ записывать данные от пользователя в строку.
И уже в строке проверять, нет ли в ней чего лишнего кроме цифр, так же можно проверить не выходил ли за диапазон int`a. Ну а потом строку переводить в int.